# PL SQL Temporary Table

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, plsql-psp

I need to create a key-value pair in PL SQL.

I know that Oracle doesn't have the same concept of temporary tables as SQL Server does but it'd help me to convert a split string into a hash, array or similar to process it. My problem is that, every time I try to use an associative array (index-by table), I get the following error:

`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "REPORTTABTYP" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;`

This is the declaration of my associative array:

```
create or replace procedure "POST_TX"
(p_report IN VARCHAR2)
is
begin
    TYPE ReportTabTyp IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
    ReportTab ReportTabTyp := ReportTabTyp();
```

Similarly, I've tried to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY in the procedure to create a temporary table but, since it doesn't exist, the procedure fails to compile.

Here's my full procedure:

```
create or replace procedure "POST_TX"
(p_report IN VARCHAR2)
is
begin
    TYPE ReportTabTyp IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(64);
    ReportTab ReportTabTyp := ReportTabTyp();

FOR loop_words IN
        (select level as ID, regexp_substr(p_report,'[^ ]+', 1, level) as report
        from dual
        connect by regexp_substr(p_report, '[^ ]+', 1, level) is not null)
    LOOP
        ReportTab(loop_words.ID) := loop_words.report;
    END LOOP loop_words;

    IF (LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(ReportTabTyp(2).report, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL) THEN
        -- Do stuff
    ELSE
        -- Output error
    END IF;
end;
```

Comment: Not sure what sort of processing you're aiming for, but you may also be interested in apex_string package https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type and variable should be declared *before* the `begin`. You also seem to have the datatypes swapped over.

```
create or replace procedure "POST_TX"
(p_report IN VARCHAR2)
is
    TYPE ReportTabTyp IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(64) INDEX BY NUMBER;
    ReportTab ReportTabTyp := ReportTabTyp();
begin
...
```

Comment: Thanks! It ended up looking like this:

    is
        TYPE ReportTabTyp IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(128) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
        ReportTab ReportTabTyp;
    begin

Answer (score 1):

You can create global temporary table in oracle and use in your session - [GTT](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefdeclaretemptable.html)